# Overriding previously set CSS

Tags: css

My css:

```
.pic img:hover {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="pic">
  <img src="hey.jpg">
  <img class="overlay" src="overlay.jpg">
</div>
```

I have an "overlay.jpg" that is placed in the bottom corner of the first image.
Problem with the css is that the overlay gets the :hover effect too.

The actual code is very complicated, I know the best solution would be to add a class to the first image and hover only that, but that will take more time than what i currently have to get this fixed.

The code has a class for the overlay images though, so I'm asking if theres a way to override the hover by setting some other css for the overlay class.

However `.overlay:hover { border: none; }` does not do the trick, even if i put it after the css above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is less **specific** than the previous one so it is getting overridden.

You have to change it to:

```
.pic .overlay:hover { border: none; }
```

> **The concept**
>
> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which
>   property values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be
>   applied. Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are
>   composed of selectors of different sorts.
>
> **How is it calculated?**
>
> The specificity is calculated on the
>   concatenation of the count of each selectors type. It is not a weight
>   that is applied to the corresponding matching expression.
>
> In case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the
>   CSS is applied to the element.

Reference: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2):

As long as overlay always comes after the first image, you can use `:first-child` to pick only the first image:

```
.pic img:first-child:hover {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

It's [supported in everything](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) (excluding IE6, but I don't count that as a thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `:not` selector:

```
.pic img:not(.overlay):hover {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

This way you won't have to worry about the order of the images and also don't have to worry about specificity by including another reset style.

Comment: Nice, but do check that your supported browsers can handle `:not` on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: Yup. All modern browsers do.

Comment: Sadly not everybody has the luxury of only supporting modern browsers.